# "createComponents" in Lucene was only called sometimes, why?

Tags: java, lucene

I have my own analyzer with the method

```
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName, final Reader reader){}
```

But I noticed that this method was not called all the time.

If the given String is: "two words", and then it will be called.

If the given String is : "two-words", then it will not be called.

If the given String is : "two/words", then it will not be called.

But I thought I could use the tokenizer in this method to parse my string.

My goal is:

"two words" should be thought as two AND words

"two-words" should also be thought as two AND words

So is "two/words", it should be also parsed into two AND words.

That is why I am using my own analyzer. But I'm so surprised that the analyzer was not called in the latter two examples.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzer components can be re-used, so if you index several documents at once, you'll get only a single call of `createComponents()`.

To make sure that you data streams are analyzed correctly, use some kind of logging in `incrementToken()` method of `Tokenizer` and/or filters. Or, better, temporarily append a logging filter on the top of the filter chain, and log all invocations of `incrementToken()`, `reset()`, `close()`, `end()` methods during the analyzing phase. This helps to understand better the tokenizer and filters lifecycles.